# Angular2 ViewChild in template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following view (interests.component.html):

```
<Tree #tree [nodes]="nodes" [options]="treeOptions">
  <template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
    <inline-editor #nodeEdit type="text" [(ngModel)]="node.data.name" (onEdit)="beginEditable($event)" (onSave)="saveEditable($event)" name="node{{node.data.id}}" size="8"></inline-editor>

      <a (click)="addNode(node)"><i class="pull-right btn btn-xs icon-plus"></i></a>
      <a (click)="editNode(node)"><i class="pull-right btn btn-xs icon-note"></i></a>
      <a (click)="deleteNode(node)"><i class="pull-right btn btn-xs icon-trash"></i></a>
  </template>
</Tree>
```

My component looks like this(interests.component.ts):

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from "lodash";
import * as $ from "jquery";

import { AppState } from '../app.service';
import {TreeModule, TreeNode, TREE_ACTIONS, KEYS, IActionMapping } from 'angular2-tree-component';
import {InlineEditorComponent} from 'ng2-inline-editor';

@Component({
  selector: 'interests',
  providers: [],
  styleUrls: ['./interests.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './interests.component.html'
})
export class Interests {
  @ViewChild('tree') tree: any;
  @ViewChildren('nodeEdit') nodeEdits: any;

  /** Level multiplikator for tree id creation. */
  public static readonly LEVEL_MULTIPLIKATOR = 100000;

  /** Last inline text element which is/was in edit mode. */
  public lastSelectedEditElement: any;

  /** Id of last selected edit node. */
  public lastSelectedEditId: number;

  /** Options for the tree component. */
  treeOptions = {
    allowDrag: true
  };

  /** contains the tree nodes. */
  nodes: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.nodeEdits);
  }

}
```

I want to get the `inline-editor` on an edit click to call an edit function, but I'm not able to get a ref to this object.
I've tried the following viewChildren:

```
@ViewChildren('nodeEdit') nodeEdits: any;
```

But it is always undefined.
To get the `tree` or `treeNodeTemplate` works as expected.

Hope somebody is able to help me :)

**Update**

I try to access `this.nodeEdits` on an edit button click so `ngAfterViewInit()` is called before that.

I try to access it from my Interest controller which is the controller for the view.

Comment: where do you access it?

Comment: Add what point is it `undefined`? `NgOnInit`? `NgAfterViewInit`? Need a little more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `nodeEdits` in `ngOnInit()` or the constructor. Only when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called `this.nodeEdits` is set.

Comment: It is also undefined in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Please add more code that makes it more obvious what you are doing. Where is the HTML, where is `@ViewChildren()`, ...